# Анимация вращение текста вокруг элемента svg

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как написать анимацию вращения текста вокруг логотипа человека?
Картинка в svg, все буквы имеют общий класс.
Это вообще возможно сделать с простым svg?

```html
 <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
 <defs>
      <style>
        .cls-1 {
          fill: #e96f00;
        }

        .cls-1,
        .cls-2 {
          fill-rule: evenodd;
        }

        .cls-2 {
          fill: #0076af;
        }
      </style>
    </defs>
    <title>Лого</title>
    <polygon class="cls-2"
      points="157.78 26.34 156.64 26.34 156.64 26.63 155.5 26.63 155.5 26.92 153.78 26.92 153.78 27.2 152.34 27.2 152.34 27.49 150.91 27.49 150.91 27.78 149.19 27.78 149.19 28.06 148.05 28.06 148.05 28.35 147.19 28.35 147.19 28.64 145.76 28.64 145.76 28.92 144.9 28.92 144.9 29.21 143.47 29.21 143.47 29.5 142.32 29.5 142.32 29.78 141.75 29.78 141.75 30.07 140.32 30.07 140.32 30.36 139.46 30.36 139.46 30.64 138.6 30.64 138.6 30.93 137.74 30.93 137.74 31.21 136.59 31.21 136.59 31.5 135.74 31.5 135.74 31.79 134.88 31.79 134.88 32.07 134.3 32.07 134.3 32.36 133.44 32.36 133.44 32.65 132.59 32.65 132.59 32.93 132.01 32.93 132.01 33.22 131.73 33.22 131.73 33.5 130.3 33.5 130.3 34.08 129.15 34.08 129.15 34.36 128.58 34.36 128.58 34.65 128 34.65 128 34.94 127.43 34.94 127.43 35.22 126.86 35.22 126.86 35.51 126.29 35.51 126.29 35.8 125.71 35.8 125.71 36.08 124.85 36.08 124.85 36.37 124.28 36.37 124.28 36.66 123.71 36.66 123.71 36.94 123.42 36.94 123.42 37.23 122.85 37.23 122.85 37.51 121.99 37.51 121.99 37.8 121.42 37.8 121.42 38.09 121.13 38.09 121.13 38.37 120.56 38.37 120.56 38.66 120.27 38.66 120.27 38.95 119.7 38.95 119.7 39.23 119.13 39.23 119.13 39.52 118.84 39.52 118.84 39.8 117.98 39.8 117.98 40.09 117.69 40.09 117.69 40.38 117.41 40.38 117.41 40.66 116.84 40.66 116.84 40.95 116.55 40.95 116.55 41.24 115.98 41.24 115.98 41.52 115.69 41.52 115.69 41.81 115.12 41.81 115.12 42.1 114.83 42.1 114.83 42.38 114.55 42.38 114.55 42.67 113.97 42.67 113.97 42.95 113.69 42.95 113.69 43.24 113.4 43.24 113.4 43.53 112.83 43.53 112.83 43.81 112.54 43.81 112.54 44.1 112.25 44.1 112.25 44.39 111.97 44.39 111.97 44.67 111.39 44.67 111.39 44.96 111.11 44.96 111.11 45.24 110.82 45.24 110.82 45.53 110.54 45.53 110.54 45.82 110.25 45.82 110.25 46.1 109.68 46.1 109.68 46.39 109.39 46.39 109.39 46.68 109.11 46.68 109.11 46.96 108.82 46.96 108.82 47.25 108.53 47.25 108.53 47.54 108.25 47.54 108.25 47.82 107.96 47.82 107.96 48.11 107.67 48.11 107.67 48.4 107.39 48.4 107.39 48.68 107.1 48.68 107.1 48.97 106.81 48.97 106.81 49.25 106.53 49.25 106.53 49.54 106.24 49.54 106.24 49.83 105.95 49.83 105.95 50.11 105.67 50.11 105.67 50.4 105.38 50.4 105.38 50.69 105.09 50.69 105.09 50.97 104.81 50.97 104.81 51.26 104.52 51.26 104.52 51.83 104.24 51.83 104.24 52.12 103.95 52.12 103.95 52.41 103.66 52.41 103.66 52.69 103.38 52.69 103.38 52.98 103.09 52.98 103.09 53.26 102.8 53.26 102.8 53.84 102.52 53.84 102.52 54.12 102.23 54.12 102.23 54.7 101.94 54.7 101.94 54.98 101.66 54.98 101.66 55.27 101.37 55.27 101.37 55.84 101.09 55.84 101.09 56.13 100.8 56.13 100.8 56.7 100.51 56.7 100.51 56.99 100.23 56.99 100.23 57.56 99.94 57.56 99.94 57.85 99.65 57.85 99.65 58.42 99.37 58.42 99.37 58.7 99.08 58.7 99.08 59.56 98.8 59.56 98.8 59.85 98.51 59.85 98.51 60.14 98.22 60.14 98.22 60.99 97.94 60.99 97.94 61.28 97.65 61.28 97.65 61.85 97.36 61.85 97.36 62.43 97.08 62.43 97.08 63 96.79 63 96.79 63.29 96.5 63.29 96.5 64.14 96.22 64.14 96.22 65 95.93 65 95.93 65.58 95.64 65.58 95.64 66.15 95.36 66.15 95.36 67.01 95.07 67.01 95.07 67.3 94.79 67.3 94.79 68.44 94.5 68.44 94.5 69.3 94.21 69.3 94.21 70.16 93.93 70.16 93.93 70.73 93.64 70.73 93.64 71.59 93.35 71.59 93.35 72.45 93.07 72.45 93.07 73.31 92.78 73.31 92.78 74.74 92.49 74.74 92.49 75.6 92.21 75.6 92.21 77.03 91.92 77.03 91.92 78.46 91.64 78.46 91.64 80.47 91.35 80.47 91.35 82.19 91.06 82.19 91.06 83.9 90.78 83.9 90.78 88.49 90.49 88.49 90.49 97.65 90.78 97.65 90.78 102.23 91.06 102.23 91.06 104.52 91.35 104.52 91.35 106.81 91.64 106.81 91.64 108.53 91.92 108.53 91.92 110.25 92.21 110.25 92.21 111.97 92.49 111.97 92.49 113.11 92.78 113.11 92.78 115.12 93.07 115.12 93.07 116.55 93.35 116.55 93.35 117.98 93.64 117.98 93.64 119.13 93.93 119.13 93.93 120.56 94.21 120.56 94.21 121.13 94.5 121.13 94.5 122.85 94.79 122.85 94.79 123.71 95.07 123.71 95.07 124.57 95.36 124.57 95.36 125.71 95.64 125.71 95.64 126.57 95.93 126.57 95.93 127.43 96.22 127.43 96.22 128.86 96.5 128.86 96.5 129.72 96.79 129.72 96.79 130.58 97.08 130.58 97.08 131.15 97.36 131.15 97.36 132.59 97.65 132.59 97.65 132.87 97.94 132.87 97.94 133.73 98.22 133.73 98.22 134.88 98.51 134.88 98.51 136.02 98.8 136.02 98.8 136.59 99.08 136.59 99.08 137.45 99.37 137.45 99.37 138.31 99.65 138.31 99.65 138.89 99.94 138.89 99.94 139.75 100.23 139.75 100.23 140.32 100.51 140.32 100.51 141.18 100.8 141.18 100.8 141.75 101.09 141.75 101.09 142.9 101.37 142.9 101.37 143.47 101.66 143.47 101.66 144.33 101.94 144.33 101.94 144.9 102.23 144.9 102.23 145.47 102.52 145.47 102.52 146.33 102.8 146.33 102.8 146.9 103.09 146.9 103.09 147.48 103.38 147.48 103.38 148.62 103.66 148.62 103.66 149.19 103.95 149.19 103.95 149.48 104.24 149.48 104.24 150.34 104.52 150.34 104.52 150.91 104.81 150.91 104.81 151.77 105.09 151.77 105.09 152.63 105.38 152.63 105.38 153.2 105.67 153.2 105.67 153.78 105.95 153.78 105.95 154.06 106.24 154.06 106.24 154.92 106.53 154.92 106.53 155.78 106.81 155.78 106.81 156.35 107.1 156.35 107.1 156.64 107.39 156.64 107.39 157.21 107.67 157.21 107.67 158.07 107.96 158.07 107.96 158.65 108.25 158.65 108.25 159.22 108.53 159.22 108.53 159.79 108.82 159.79 108.82 160.36 109.11 160.36 109.11 160.94 109.39 160.94 109.39 161.8 109.96 161.8 109.96 162.66 110.25 162.66 110.25 163.23 110.54 163.23 110.54 163.51 110.82 163.51 110.82 164.37 111.11 164.37 111.11 164.94 111.39 164.94 111.39 165.52 111.68 165.52 111.68 166.09 111.97 166.09 111.97 166.38 112.25 166.38 112.25 167.24 112.54 167.24 112.54 167.81 112.83 167.81 112.83 168.38 113.11 168.38 113.11 168.67 113.4 168.67 113.4 169.53 113.69 169.53 113.69 169.81 113.97 169.81 113.97 170.39 114.26 170.39 114.26 170.96 114.55 170.96 114.55 171.53 114.83 171.53 114.83 172.1 115.12 172.1 115.12 172.39 115.4 172.39 115.4 172.96 115.69 172.96 115.69 173.82 115.98 173.82 115.98 174.11 116.26 174.11 116.26 174.4 116.55 174.4 116.55 174.97 116.84 174.97 116.84 175.54 117.12 175.54 117.12 176.11 117.41 176.11 117.41 176.69 117.69 176.69 117.69 176.97 117.98 176.97 117.98 177.54 118.27 177.54 118.27 177.83 118.55 177.83 118.55 178.41 118.84 178.41 118.84 178.98 119.13 178.98 119.13 179.55 119.41 179.55 119.41 179.84 119.7 179.84 119.7 180.41 119.98 180.41 119.98 179.55 119.7 179.55 119.7 178.98 119.41 178.98 119.41 178.41 119.13 178.41 119.13 177.83 118.84 177.83 118.84 177.26 118.55 177.26 118.55 176.69 118.27 176.69 118.27 175.83 117.98 175.83 117.98 175.25 117.69 175.25 117.69 174.68 117.41 174.68 117.41 174.11 117.12 174.11 117.12 173.25 116.84 173.25 116.84 172.68 116.55 172.68 116.55 172.1 116.26 172.1 116.26 171.53 115.98 171.53 115.98 170.39 115.69 170.39 115.69 169.53 115.4 169.53 115.4 169.24 115.12 169.24 115.12 168.67 114.83 168.67 114.83 167.81 114.55 167.81 114.55 167.24 114.26 167.24 114.26 166.38 113.97 166.38 113.97 165.8 113.69 165.8 113.69 165.23 113.4 165.23 113.4 164.09 113.11 164.09 113.11 163.8 112.83 163.8 112.83 162.66 112.54 162.66 112.54 161.8 112.25 161.8 112.25 161.22 111.97 161.22 111.97 160.36 111.68 160.36 111.68 160.08 111.39 160.08 111.39 158.65 111.11 158.65 111.11 158.36 110.82 158.36 110.82 157.21 110.54 157.21 110.54 156.64 110.25 156.64 110.25 156.07 109.96 156.07 109.96 154.92 109.68 154.92 109.68 154.35 109.39 154.35 109.39 153.2 109.11 153.2 109.11 152.63 108.82 152.63 108.82 151.77 108.53 151.77 108.53 150.91 108.25 150.91 108.25 149.77 107.96 149.77 107.96 149.48 107.67 149.48 107.67 148.62 107.39 148.62 107.39 147.48 107.1 147.48 107.1 146.33 106.81 146.33 106.81 145.76 106.53 145.76 106.53 144.9 106.24 144.9 106.24 143.47 105.95 143.47 105.95 142.9 105.67 142.9 105.67 141.75 105.38 141.75 105.38 141.18 105.09 141.18 105.09 139.46 104.81 139.46 104.81 138.89 104.52 138.89 104.52 137.74 104.24 137.74 104.24 136.59 103.95 136.59 103.95 136.02 103.66 136.02 103.66 134.31 103.38 134.31 103.38 133.44 103.09 133.44 103.09 132.01 102.8 132.01 102.8 130.87 102.52 130.87 102.52 129.72 102.23 129.72 102.23 128 101.94 128 101.94 126.86 101.66 126.86 101.66 125.14 101.37 125.14 101.37 123.42 101.09 123.42 101.09 121.7 100.8 121.7 100.8 120.56 100.51 120.56 100.51 119.13 100.23 119.13 100.23 117.7 99.94 117.7 99.94 114.83 99.65 114.83 99.65 111.39 99.37 111.39 99.37 109.96 99.08 109.96 99.08 104.52 98.8 104.52 98.8 93.07 99.08 93.07 99.08 90.78 99.37 90.78 99.37 88.49 99.65 88.49 99.65 86.2 99.94 86.2 99.94 83.9 100.23 83.9 100.23 81.9 100.51 81.9 100.51 80.75 100.8 80.75 100.8 79.32 101.09 79.32 101.09 78.18 101.37 78.18 101.37 77.03 101.66 77.03 101.66 75.89 101.94 75.89 101.94 75.31 102.23 75.31 102.23 73.88 102.52 73.88 102.52 73.6 102.8 73.6 102.8 72.45 103.09 72.45 103.09 71.88 103.38 71.88 103.38 70.73 103.66 70.73 103.66 70.16 103.95 70.16 103.95 69.3 104.24 69.3 104.24 68.44 104.52 68.44 104.52 67.87 104.81 67.87 104.81 67.3 105.09 67.3 105.09 66.72 105.38 66.72 105.38 66.15 105.67 66.15 105.67 65.29 105.95 65.29 105.95 64.72 106.24 64.72 106.24 64.14 106.53 64.14 106.53 63.29 106.81 63.29 106.81 62.71 107.1 62.71 107.1 62.43 107.39 62.43 107.39 61.85 107.67 61.85 107.67 61.57 107.96 61.57 107.96 60.71 108.25 60.71 108.25 60.14 108.53 60.14 108.53 59.85 108.82 59.85 108.82 59.28 109.11 59.28 109.11 58.99 109.39 58.99 109.39 58.13 109.68 58.13 109.68 57.85 109.96 57.85 109.96 57.56 110.25 57.56 110.25 56.99 110.54 56.99 110.54 56.7 110.82 56.7 110.82 56.41 111.11 56.41 111.11 55.55 111.68 55.55 111.68 54.98 111.97 54.98 111.97 54.7 112.25 54.7 112.25 54.12 112.54 54.12 112.54 53.84 112.83 53.84 112.83 53.55 113.11 53.55 113.11 52.98 113.4 52.98 113.4 52.69 113.69 52.69 113.69 52.41 113.97 52.41 113.97 52.12 114.26 52.12 114.26 51.83 114.55 51.83 114.55 51.26 114.83 51.26 114.83 50.97 115.12 50.97 115.12 50.69 115.4 50.69 115.4 50.4 115.69 50.4 115.69 50.11 115.98 50.11 115.98 49.54 116.55 49.54 116.55 48.97 116.84 48.97 116.84 48.68 117.12 48.68 117.12 48.4 117.41 48.4 117.41 48.11 117.69 48.11 117.69 47.82 117.98 47.82 117.98 47.54 118.27 47.54 118.27 47.25 118.55 47.25 118.55 46.96 118.84 46.96 118.84 46.68 119.13 46.68 119.13 46.39 119.41 46.39 119.41 46.1 119.7 46.1 119.7 45.82 119.98 45.82 119.98 45.53 120.56 45.53 120.56 45.24 120.84 45.24 120.84 44.96 121.13 44.96 121.13 44.67 121.42 44.67 121.42 44.39 121.7 44.39 121.7 44.1 121.99 44.1 121.99 43.81 122.28 43.81 122.28 43.53 122.56 43.53 122.56 43.24 123.14 43.24 123.14 42.95 123.42 42.95 123.42 42.67 124 42.67 124 42.38 124.28 42.38 124.28 42.1 124.57 42.1 124.57 41.81 124.85 41.81 124.85 41.52 125.14 41.52 125.14 41.24 125.71 41.24 125.71 40.66 126.29 40.66 126.29 40.38 126.57 40.38 126.57 40.09 127.14 40.09 127.14 39.8 127.72 39.8 127.72 39.52 128 39.52 128 39.23 128.29 39.23 128.29 38.95 128.86 38.95 128.86 38.66 129.15 38.66 129.15 38.37 129.44 38.37 129.44 38.09 130.3 38.09 130.3 37.8 130.58 37.8 130.58 37.51 131.15 37.51 131.15 37.23 131.44 37.23 131.44 36.94 132.01 36.94 132.01 36.66 132.3 36.66 132.3 36.37 132.87 36.37 132.87 36.08 133.44 36.08 133.44 35.8 134.02 35.8 134.02 35.51 134.59 35.51 134.59 35.22 134.88 35.22 134.88 34.94 135.45 34.94 135.45 34.65 136.02 34.65 136.02 34.36 136.59 34.36 136.59 34.08 137.17 34.08 137.17 33.79 137.74 33.79 137.74 33.5 138.31 33.5 138.31 33.22 138.89 33.22 138.89 32.93 139.46 32.93 139.46 32.65 140.32 32.65 140.32 32.36 140.89 32.36 140.89 32.07 141.75 32.07 141.75 31.79 142.32 31.79 142.32 31.5 142.9 31.5 142.9 31.21 143.47 31.21 143.47 30.93 144.04 30.93 144.04 30.64 144.9 30.64 144.9 30.36 145.76 30.36 145.76 30.07 146.62 30.07 146.62 29.78 147.19 29.78 147.19 29.5 148.62 29.5 148.62 28.92 150.34 28.92 150.34 28.64 150.91 28.64 150.91 28.35 152.34 28.35 152.34 28.06 153.2 28.06 153.2 27.78 153.78 27.78 153.78 27.49 155.5 27.49 155.5 27.2 156.64 27.2 156.64 26.92 157.78 26.92 157.78 26.63 159.5 26.63 159.5 26.34 160.65 26.34 160.65 26.06 157.78 26.06 157.78 26.34" />
    <polygon class="cls-2"
      points="38.09 29.5 38.37 29.5 38.37 30.64 38.66 30.64 38.66 32.07 38.95 32.07 38.95 33.5 39.23 33.5 39.23 34.65 39.52 34.65 39.52 35.51 39.8 35.51 39.8 36.37 40.09 36.37 40.09 37.8 40.38 37.8 40.38 38.66 40.66 38.66 40.66 39.52 40.95 39.52 40.95 40.38 41.24 40.38 41.24 40.95 41.52 40.95 41.52 42.1 41.81 42.1 41.81 42.67 42.1 42.67 42.1 43.53 42.38 43.53 42.38 44.1 42.67 44.1 42.67 44.67 42.95 44.67 42.95 45.53 43.24 45.53 43.24 46.1 43.53 46.1 43.53 46.68 43.81 46.68 43.81 47.25 44.1 47.25 44.1 47.82 44.39 47.82 44.39 48.4 44.67 48.4 44.67 48.97 44.96 48.97 44.96 49.54 45.24 49.54 45.24 50.11 45.53 50.11 45.53 50.4 45.82 50.4 45.82 50.97 46.1 50.97 46.1 51.55 46.39 51.55 46.39 51.83 46.68 51.83 46.68 52.41 46.96 52.41 46.96 52.69 47.25 52.69 47.25 53.26 47.54 53.26 47.54 53.55 47.82 53.55 47.82 54.12 48.11 54.12 48.11 54.41 48.4 54.41 48.4 54.7 48.68 54.7 48.68 54.98 48.97 54.98 48.97 55.55 49.26 55.55 49.26 55.84 49.54 55.84 49.54 56.13 49.83 56.13 49.83 56.41 50.11 56.41 50.11 65.58 50.4 65.58 50.4 70.16 50.69 70.16 50.69 71.88 50.97 71.88 50.97 73.88 51.26 73.88 51.26 76.17 51.55 76.17 51.55 77.6 51.83 77.6 51.83 79.32 52.12 79.32 52.12 80.18 52.4 80.18 52.4 81.61 52.69 81.61 52.69 83.05 52.98 83.05 52.98 84.48 53.26 84.48 53.26 85.62 53.55 85.62 53.55 87.06 53.84 87.06 53.84 87.63 54.12 87.63 54.12 89.34 54.41 89.34 54.41 89.92 54.69 89.92 54.69 91.35 54.98 91.35 54.98 91.92 55.27 91.92 55.27 93.07 55.55 93.07 55.55 94.5 55.84 94.5 55.84 95.36 56.13 95.36 56.13 95.93 56.41 95.93 56.41 97.08 56.7 97.08 56.7 97.65 56.99 97.65 56.99 98.8 57.27 98.8 57.27 99.94 57.56 99.94 57.56 100.51 57.84 100.51 57.84 101.66 58.13 101.66 58.13 102.23 58.42 102.23 58.42 103.38 58.7 103.38 58.7 103.95 58.99 103.95 58.99 105.09 59.28 105.09 59.28 105.95 59.56 105.95 59.56 106.81 59.85 106.81 59.85 107.1 60.14 107.1 60.14 107.96 60.42 107.96 60.42 109.1 60.71 109.1 60.71 109.96 60.99 109.96 60.99 110.25 61.28 110.25 61.28 111.39 61.57 111.39 61.57 111.97 61.85 111.97 61.85 112.83 62.14 112.83 62.14 113.69 62.43 113.69 62.43 114.55 62.71 114.55 62.71 115.12 63 115.12 63 115.98 63.29 115.98 63.29 116.55 63.57 116.55 63.57 117.12 63.86 117.12 63.86 117.7 64.14 117.7 64.14 118.84 64.43 118.84 64.43 119.41 64.72 119.41 64.72 119.99 65 119.99 65 120.84 65.29 120.84 65.29 121.42 65.58 121.42 65.58 122.28 65.86 122.28 65.86 122.85 66.15 122.85 66.15 123.71 66.44 123.71 66.44 124.28 66.72 124.28 66.72 124.86 67.01 124.86 67.01 125.71 67.3 125.71 67.3 126 67.58 126 67.58 126.86 67.87 126.86 67.87 127.43 68.15 127.43 68.15 128.29 68.44 128.29 68.44 128.86 68.73 128.86 68.73 129.72 69.01 129.72 69.01 130.29 69.3 130.29 69.3 130.87 69.59 130.87 69.59 131.44 69.87 131.44 69.87 132.01 70.16 132.01 70.16 132.87 70.45 132.87 70.45 133.44 70.73 133.44 70.73 134.31 71.02 134.31 71.02 134.59 71.31 134.59 71.31 135.45 71.59 135.45 71.59 136.02 71.88 136.02 71.88 136.59 72.16 136.59 72.16 137.17 72.45 137.17 72.45 137.74 72.74 137.74 72.74 138.6 73.02 138.6 73.02 139.17 73.31 139.17 73.31 139.75 73.59 139.75 73.59 140.32 73.88 140.32 73.88 140.89 74.17 140.89 74.17 141.46 74.45 141.46 74.45 142.04 74.74 142.04 74.74 142.61 75.03 142.61 75.03 143.47 75.31 143.47 75.31 144.04 75.6 144.04 75.6 144.61 75.89 144.61 75.89 145.19 76.17 145.19 76.17 145.76 76.46 145.76 76.46 146.33 76.75 146.33 76.75 146.9 77.03 146.9 77.03 147.48 77.32 147.48 77.32 148.05 77.6 148.05 77.6 148.62 77.89 148.62 77.89 149.19 78.18 149.19 78.18 149.77 78.46 149.77 78.46 150.34 78.75 150.34 78.75 150.91 79.04 150.91 79.04 151.49 79.32 151.49 79.32 152.06 79.61 152.06 79.61 152.63 79.9 152.63 79.9 153.2 80.18 153.2 80.18 153.78 80.47 153.78 80.47 154.35 80.75 154.35 80.75 154.92 81.04 154.92 81.04 155.5 81.33 155.5 81.33 156.07 81.61 156.07 81.61 156.64 81.9 156.64 81.9 157.21 82.19 157.21 82.19 157.78 82.47 157.78 82.47 158.36 82.76 158.36 82.76 158.93 83.05 158.93 83.05 159.5 83.33 159.5 83.33 160.08 83.62 160.08 83.62 160.65 83.9 160.65 83.9 161.22 84.19 161.22 84.19 161.8 84.48 161.8 84.48 162.08 84.76 162.08 84.76 162.66 85.05 162.66 85.05 163.23 85.34 163.23 85.34 163.8 85.62 163.8 85.62 164.37 85.91 164.37 85.91 164.94 86.2 164.94 86.2 165.52 86.48 165.52 86.48 166.09 86.77 166.09 86.77 166.66 87.05 166.66 87.05 167.24 87.34 167.24 87.34 167.52 87.63 167.52 87.63 168.09 87.91 168.09 87.91 168.67 88.2 168.67 88.2 169.24 88.49 169.24 88.49 169.81 88.77 169.81 88.77 170.1 89.06 170.1 89.06 170.67 89.34 170.67 89.34 171.25 89.63 171.25 89.63 171.82 89.92 171.82 89.92 172.39 90.2 172.39 90.2 172.96 90.49 172.96 90.49 173.25 90.78 173.25 90.78 173.82 91.06 173.82 91.06 174.4 91.35 174.4 91.35 174.97 91.64 174.97 91.64 175.54 91.92 175.54 91.92 175.83 92.21 175.83 92.21 176.4 92.49 176.4 92.49 176.97 92.78 176.97 92.78 177.54 93.07 177.54 93.07 178.12 93.35 178.12 93.35 178.69 93.64 178.69 93.64 178.98 93.93 178.98 93.93 178.41 93.64 178.41 93.64 177.83 93.35 177.83 93.35 177.26 93.07 177.26 93.07 176.69 92.78 176.69 92.78 176.11 92.49 176.11 92.49 175.54 92.21 175.54 92.21 174.97 91.92 174.97 91.92 174.68 91.64 174.68 91.64 173.82 91.35 173.82 91.35 173.25 91.06 173.25 91.06 172.68 90.78 172.68 90.78 172.1 90.49 172.1 90.49 171.53 90.2 171.53 90.2 170.96 89.92 170.96 89.92 170.39 89.63 170.39 89.63 169.81 89.34 169.81 89.34 169.24 89.06 169.24 89.06 168.67 88.77 168.67 88.77 168.09 88.49 168.09 88.49 167.52 88.2 167.52 88.2 166.95 87.91 166.95 87.91 166.38 87.63 166.38 87.63 165.8 87.34 165.8 87.34 164.94 87.05 164.94 87.05 164.37 86.77 164.37 86.77 163.8 86.48 163.8 86.48 163.23 86.2 163.23 86.2 162.66 85.91 162.66 85.91 162.08 85.62 162.08 85.62 161.51 85.34 161.51 85.34 160.94 85.05 160.94 85.05 160.36 84.76 160.36 84.76 159.5 84.48 159.5 84.48 158.93 84.19 158.93 84.19 158.36 83.9 158.36 83.9 157.78 83.62 157.78 83.62 157.21 83.33 157.21 83.33 156.35 83.05 156.35 83.05 155.78 82.76 155.78 82.76 155.21 82.47 155.21 82.47 154.35 82.19 154.35 82.19 153.78 81.9 153.78 81.9 153.2 81.61 153.2 81.61 152.63 81.33 152.63 81.33 152.06 81.04 152.06 81.04 151.2 80.75 151.2 80.75 150.63 80.47 150.63 80.47 149.77 80.18 149.77 80.18 149.19 79.9 149.19 79.9 148.62 79.61 148.62 79.61 148.05 79.32 148.05 79.32 147.19 79.04 147.19 79.04 146.62 78.75 146.62 78.75 145.76 78.46 145.76 78.46 145.19 78.18 145.19 78.18 144.61 77.89 144.61 77.89 144.04 77.6 144.04 77.6 143.18 77.32 143.18 77.32 142.32 77.03 142.32 77.03 141.75 76.75 141.75 76.75 141.18 76.46 141.18 76.46 140.32 76.17 140.32 76.17 139.46 75.89 139.46 75.89 138.89 75.6 138.89 75.6 138.03 75.31 138.03 75.31 137.17 75.03 137.17 75.03 136.59 74.74 136.59 74.74 135.74 74.45 135.74 74.45 135.16 74.17 135.16 74.17 134.31 73.88 134.31 73.88 133.73 73.59 133.73 73.59 132.87 73.31 132.87 73.31 132.01 73.02 132.01 73.02 131.44 72.74 131.44 72.74 130.58 72.45 130.58 72.45 129.72 72.16 129.72 72.16 128.86 71.88 128.86 71.88 128 71.59 128 71.59 127.43 71.31 127.43 71.31 126.29 71.02 126.29 71.02 125.71 70.73 125.71 70.73 125.14 70.45 125.14 70.45 124 70.16 124 70.16 123.14 69.87 123.14 69.87 122.28 69.59 122.28 69.59 121.7 69.3 121.7 69.3 120.56 69.01 120.56 69.01 119.99 68.73 119.99 68.73 119.13 68.44 119.13 68.44 118.27 68.15 118.27 68.15 117.41 67.87 117.41 67.87 116.55 67.58 116.55 67.58 115.69 67.3 115.69 67.3 114.55 67.01 114.55 67.01 113.69 66.72 113.69 66.72 112.54 66.44 112.54 66.44 111.97 66.15 111.97 66.15 110.82 65.86 110.82 65.86 109.68 65.58 109.68 65.58 108.53 65.29 108.53 65.29 107.67 65 107.67 65 106.81 64.72 106.81 64.72 105.67 64.43 105.67 
  </svg>
```

Comment: да, это возможно

Comment: @МихаилКамахин можете помощь оказать?

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров У вас же есть файл svg/ Так добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Вы для начала сделайте текст по кругу потом его вращение ну а позже разместите фигуру

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для анимации текста вдоль кривой используется - [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath)

Чтобы реализовать движение текста вокруг объекта, необходимо нарисовать в векторном редакторе линию, которая будет окружать этот объект.

Код SVG исходного объекта, представлен в вопросе не полностью, лишь фрагмент его. Да и он в урезанном виде достаточно большой.

Так как объект SVG (лого) не участвует в анимации, то можно заменить его растровым изображением. И код будет короче и вес файла меньше.

Для анимации движения букв вдоль кривой используется изменение атрибута `startOffset`

```
<animate id="an1" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click;an1.end+0.3s"
   dur="6s" values="105%;0%"
         repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"  />
```

```css
#txt {
fill:#EB7001;
font-family:cursive,arial;
font-size:32px;
font-weight:700;
font-style:italic;
letter-spacing:12px;
word-spacing: 35px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300"  viewBox="0 0 230 250"  version="1.1" >
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ErO.jpg" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  
  <path id="trace"  d="M53.6 89A96.4 96.4 0 0 0 18 112.8C8.3 123.7-1 137-2.6 151.5a74.6 74.6 0 0 0 12.2 48.2c8.8 13.5 23.6 22.7 38.1 29.6 18.9 9 40.1 13.3 61 14.3a121 121 0 0 0 32.3-4.2 134 134 0 0 0 34.4-11.1c17.9-9.7 37.2-20.7 47.7-38.2 6.9-11.5 7.9-26.2 7.4-39.7a53.8 53.8 0 0 0-5.9-22 84.5 84.5 0 0 0-22.7-28.3 123.9 123.9 0 0 0-58.3-27c-30.2-4-61.8 4.5-90 15.9Z" id="path817" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".8" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-opacity="1"/>
  <text id="txt"  dy="-2" > 
     <textPath  xlink:href="#trace"      startOffset="0%" >
          aтмосфера спорта 
        <animate id="an1" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click;an1.end+0.3s" dur="6s" values="105%;0%"
         repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"  />   
     </textPath> 
 </text> 
</svg>
```

Выглядит не очень впечатляюще. Буквы при прохождении нужно спрятать за логотип.

Для этого можно использовать такой прием:

1. Использовать вместо одного, два изображения логотипа.
2. Нарисовать маску по контурам логотипа
3. Ко второму изображению применить маску, которая спрячет буквы при прохождении заднего плана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Анимация начнется после клика.*

`begin="svg1.click;an1.end+1.3s"` Эта запись означает: первый запуск после клика `svg1.click` : пауза **1.3s** после окончания анимации `an1.end+1.3s` и снова запуск анимации.

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
#txt {
fill:#EB7001;
font-family:cursive;
font-size:36px;
font-weight:700;
font-style:italic;
letter-spacing:12px;
word-spacing: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 230 250"  version="1.1" >
  <defs> 
              <!-- Маска -->
  <mask id="mask"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
    <path id="path" fill="white" d="M37.1 1.6c-11.8 17.6 6.3 44 8 66.2.4 5.3-.5 10.7.5 15.9 4 20 12.8 38.7 21.2 57.2a359 359 0 0 0 36 65.7c6.8 9.2 22.6 8.2 34 6.3 9.3-1.5 22.5-4.6 24.8-13.7 4.7-18.5-23.8-30.5-30.7-48.2-6.5-16.6-12.7-35-9.5-52.5 3-17.1 13.8-33 26.4-45 11.2-10.5 32.9-8.1 40.8-21.2 4.6-7.5 6.2-20.2 0-26.5C148.6-.6 80.3 3 37.1 1.6Z" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
                       <!-- Первой изображение -->
  <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ErO.jpg" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
  
  <path  id="trace"  d="M53.6 89A96.4 96.4 0 0 0 18 112.8C8.3 123.7-1 137-2.6 151.5a74.6 74.6 0 0 0 12.2 48.2c8.8 13.5 23.6 22.7 38.1 29.6 18.9 9 40.1 13.3 61 14.3a121 121 0 0 0 32.3-4.2 134 134 0 0 0 34.4-11.1c17.9-9.7 37.2-20.7 47.7-38.2 6.9-11.5 7.9-26.2 7.4-39.7a53.8 53.8 0 0 0-5.9-22 84.5 84.5 0 0 0-22.7-28.3 123.9 123.9 0 0 0-58.3-27c-30.2-4-61.8 4.5-90 15.9Z"  fill="#FCFCFC" />
 
 <text id="txt"  dy="-2" > 
      <textPath  xlink:href="#trace"      startOffset="5%" >
          aтмосфера спорта 
        <animate id="an1" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click;an1.end+1.3s" dur="12s" values="5%;105%;5%"
         repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"  />   
     </textPath> 
 </text>  
                  <!-- Второе изображение, к которому применена маска -->
  
  <image mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ErO.jpg" id="image3" height="100%" width="100%"/>   
 
</svg>
</div>
```

***Второй вариант:***
синий цвет букв, вращение в противоположную сторону

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
#txt {
fill:#347FA7;
font-family:cursive;
font-size:36px;
font-weight:700;
font-style:italic;
letter-spacing:11px;
word-spacing: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 230 250"  version="1.1" >
  <defs> 
              <!-- Маска -->
  <mask id="mask"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
    <path id="path" fill="white" d="M37.1 1.6c-11.8 17.6 6.3 44 8 66.2.4 5.3-.5 10.7.5 15.9 4 20 12.8 38.7 21.2 57.2a359 359 0 0 0 36 65.7c6.8 9.2 22.6 8.2 34 6.3 9.3-1.5 22.5-4.6 24.8-13.7 4.7-18.5-23.8-30.5-30.7-48.2-6.5-16.6-12.7-35-9.5-52.5 3-17.1 13.8-33 26.4-45 11.2-10.5 32.9-8.1 40.8-21.2 4.6-7.5 6.2-20.2 0-26.5C148.6-.6 80.3 3 37.1 1.6Z" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
                       <!-- Первой изображение -->
  <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ErO.jpg" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
  
  <path  id="trace"  d="M53.6 89A96.4 96.4 0 0 0 18 112.8C8.3 123.7-1 137-2.6 151.5a74.6 74.6 0 0 0 12.2 48.2c8.8 13.5 23.6 22.7 38.1 29.6 18.9 9 40.1 13.3 61 14.3a121 121 0 0 0 32.3-4.2 134 134 0 0 0 34.4-11.1c17.9-9.7 37.2-20.7 47.7-38.2 6.9-11.5 7.9-26.2 7.4-39.7a53.8 53.8 0 0 0-5.9-22 84.5 84.5 0 0 0-22.7-28.3 123.9 123.9 0 0 0-58.3-27c-30.2-4-61.8 4.5-90 15.9Z"  fill="#FCFCFC" />
 
 <text id="txt"  dy="-2" > 
      <textPath  xlink:href="#trace"      startOffset="2%" >
          aтмосфера спорта 
        <animate id="an1" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click-1s;an1.end" dur="12s" values="110%;2%;2%;110%"
         repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"  />   
     </textPath> 
 </text>  
                  <!-- Второе изображение, к которому применена маска -->
  
  <image mask="url(#mask)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ErO.jpg" id="image3" height="100%" width="100%"/>   
 
</svg>
</div>
```

[***LIVE DEMO***](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/ExbjEyZ)